# SQL Query to return Geography type as XML

Tags: sql, xml, sqlgeography

I'm trying to return an XML from a table which holds a Geography type.
SQL query:

```
SELECT *
From Events
ORDER BY HydrantId ASC
FOR XML RAW ('Event'), ROOT ('Events'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
FOR XML does not support CLR types -   
cast CLR types explicitly into one of the supported types in FOR XML queries.
```

How can I cast this Geography column to something which is readable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, cast(GeographyColumn as varchar(max))
From Events
ORDER BY HydrantId ASC
FOR XML RAW ('Event'), ROOT ('Events'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

The value in `GeographyColumn` will be in the `POINT (-77.010996 38.890358)` format.

Comment: Thanks. How can I insert the new POINT into his own XML child element? I'm getting the following error: `System.Data.SqlServer.TruncationException: Trying to convert return value or output parameter of size 64 bytes to a T-SQL type with a smaller size limit of 60 bytes.`

Comment: I've solve the error by using `cast(GeographyColumn as nvarchar(MAX))`.

Comment: Eeks I forgot to get the data length. Fixed!

Comment: How can I insert the new POINT into his own XML child element?